# Tail recursion vs recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, visual-studio-2015

I have two functions. One is the "normal" recursion and the other is a tail recursion:

the "normal" recursion:

```
    int factorial(int num)
    {
        if (num == 1)
            return num;
        return num*factorial(num - 1);
    }
```

tail recursion:

```
int factorial_n(int num,int acc=1)
{
    if (num == 1)
        return acc;
    return factorial_n(num - 1,acc);
}
int call(int num)
{
    return factorial_n(num, 1);
}
```

I am trying to visualize the difference in the stack when using tail recursion,
using visual studio's call stack in debug mode ,but I cant see any difference!
Am I misunderstanding something?
How can I visualize the difference between these two functions?

Comment: A side not: `int call(int num)`  could be better named  `int  factorial_(int num)`

Comment: [Viewing the Call Stack in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/viewing-the-call-stack-in-visual-studio)

Comment: What makes you expect any difference? C++ the language has no special treatment for tail recursion. It's up to an implementation to deal with it. An implementation is unlikely to apply tail call optimisations in debug mode (if it bothers at all).

Comment: Another way to think about it: a tail-recursive function *allows for* more more efficient use of the stack.  But it doesn't *require* it.  It's up to a compiler or interpreter to decide.  Some language specs require this optimization, especially in functional languages.  C++ does not.  (In JavaScript, it's somewhat worse: the specification requires it, but almost no implementations do so.)

Comment: The canonical example of a language that requires tail-call optimization is Scheme. But other Lisp dialects don't.

Comment: The "tail recursive" case has a significant logic error: It's missing any multiplication operation.

Answer (score 0):

In tail recursion there is no computation after function returns. In theory it can be optimized.

By the way, what factorial_n function is doing?

Comment: There's a bug in `factorial_n`. it should be `return factorial_n(num - 1,acc*num);`

Comment: @Mooing Duck yeah!